# I can't set up a vhost on Windows 8

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a virtual host on Windows 8 with Wamp. My Apache version is 2.4.4. I think I've done everything I'm suposed to do but for some reason it's not working. I keep getting this error message:

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I added this at the end of the 'hosts' file:

```
127.0.0.1       l.mysite
```

I added this at the end of the 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite"
    ServerName l.mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you uncomment this `Include` from your httpd.conf file?

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Its at the bottom of the file around line 498.

Comment: Yes, I uncommented that Include. I fixed the problem using Xampp. Thanks!